# Не могу настроить размер кнопок в jPanel

Tags: java, swing

Есть фрейм в который я добавляю панель, в ней содержится три кнопки, но не получается увеличить их размер вот код:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Launcher");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Font font = new Font("Lack", Font.LAYOUT_NO_LIMIT_CONTEXT,30);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Добро пожаловать " + account.getLogin() + "!");
    label.setFont(font);
    panel.add(label);

    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    btGames = new JButton("Игры");
    btGames.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    btGames.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    btOptions = new JButton("Настройки");
    btOptions.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    btOptions.setSize(btGames.getSize());
    btOptions.setPreferredSize(btGames.getPreferredSize());
    btExit = new JButton("Выход");
    btExit.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    buttonsPanel.add(btGames);
    buttonsPanel.add(btOptions);
    buttonsPanel.add(btExit);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,buttonsPanel);
    frame.setLocation(500,100);
    frame.setSize(1000,720);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

А ещё подскажите как между кнопками установить расстояние!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BoxLayout, скорей всего, растягивает ваши кнопки, чтоб этого не происходило задайте им максимальный и минимальный размеры.

```
...
btGames = new JButton("Игры");
btGames.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
Dimension d = new Dimension(700,200);
btGames.setMinimumSize(d);
btGames.setPreferredSize(d);
btGames.setMaximumSize(d);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй написать setLayout(null)